# How can I properly type the event parameter in an onChange handler that I want to use with both <input/> and <textarea/>?

Tags: typescript, react-redux, functional-programming, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am using React, Redux, and Typescript to create a kanban application, and I am specifically trying to employ the functional programming paradigm. I have a function `onChangeFor` that takes a `key` parameter and returns a function that is to be the event handler for either `<textarea/>` or `<input/>` elements. The `key` parameter is used to update a `task` attribute associated with the corresponding form element.

The `onChangeFor` return function's input is the event from the corresponding form element, and is currently typed as `any`. I could have typed it as `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextareaElement>`, but the way I use it when updating the list of subtasks breaks the ability to do that. How can I define a type for the event parameter to satisfy all three ways I am using the function?

I will paste the entire component in here to paint the full picture.

```js
export default function AddTask() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [task, setTask] = useState<ITaskConstructor>({
    subtasks: ["", ""],
    title: "",
    description: "",
    id: "",
  });
  const { subtasks, title, description } = task;

  const selectedBoard = useAppSelector(getSelectedBoard);
  const { data: columns } = useGetColumnsQuery(selectedBoard?.id);

  const columnNames = useMemo(() => {
    if (columns?.entities) {
      return Object.values(columns?.entities).map((col) => col?.name || "");
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }, [columns]);

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(
    columns?.entities[columns.ids[0]].name || ""
  );

  const subPlaceholders = ["e.g. Make Coffee", "e.g. Drink cofee & smile"];
  const descPlaceholder =
    "e.g. It's always good to take a break. This 15 minute break will recharge the batteries a little. ";

  function onChangeFor(key: string) {
    return (e: any) => {
      setTask((pre) => {
        return {
          ...pre,
          [key]: e.target.value,
        };
      });
    };
  }


  return (
    <ModalWBackdrop
      onOutsideClick={() => {
        dispatch(addTaskModalOpened({ open: false }));
      }}
    >
      <>
        <h2 className="ml-2 font-semibold tracking-tight mb-3 dark:text-primary-gray-400">
          Add New Task
        </h2>

        <form
          className="flex flex-col mx-2"
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
          }}
        >
          <label htmlFor="title" className="modalSubtitle">
            Title
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="title"
            placeholder="e.g. Take coffee break"
            className="modalInput"
            value={title}
            onChange={onChangeFor("title")}
          />

          <label htmlFor="description" className="modalSubtitle mt-6">
            Description
          </label>
          <textarea
            name="description"
            rows={5}
            className="modalInput"
            placeholder={descPlaceholder}
            value={description}
            onChange={onChangeFor("description")}
          />

          <fieldset className="flex flex-col mt-6">
            <legend className="modalSubtitle">Subtasks</legend>
            {subtasks.map((subtask, index) => {
              const i = index > 0 ? 1 : 0;
              return (
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <input
                    placeholder={subPlaceholders[i]}
                    value={subtask}
                    className="modalInput my-1 flex-grow"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      const onChange = onChangeFor("subtasks");
                      const newSubtasks = subtasks.slice();
                      newSubtasks.splice(index, 1, e.target.value);
                      onChange({ target: { value: newSubtasks } });
                    }}
                  />
                  <button className="w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 ml-2">
                    <X />
                  </button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </fieldset>
          <button className="fullBtnSecondary">+ Add New Subtask</button>

          <DropdownList
            label="Status"
            onChange={(status) => {
              setStatus(status);
            }}
            items={columnNames}
            selected={status}
          />

          <button type="submit" className="fullBtnPrimary">
            Create Task
          </button>
        </form>
      </>
    </ModalWBackdrop>
  );
}
```

The code above works completely fine, I am just not satisfied with the way the function is typed. Also, this situation is contrived particularly to try and think in a more FP way, which I am new to, so any other advice is appreciated. Also, here is a picture so you can put an image to the code:
[![task modal in kanban board][1]][1]

Ideally, the type would express something like "there could be different types passed, but they all need to have a target attribute, with a value attribute inside."

EDIT: This is by no means complete code, it works without error and you can change the inputs but that's as far as I am at this point. The buttons don't do anything right now.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pWKZ.png

Comment: As far as I understand your code, "key" parameter in "onChangeFor" function should not just be any string, it should be key of your "ITaskConstructor" (which specifies type of task object). Then you can specify the type of the event in returned function as you proposed ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextareaElement>

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextareaElement>`, what error are you getting?

Comment: @Marat you're right, that was an oversight thank you.

Comment: @Bergi The inputs inside of the fieldset call the onChange function with `{ target: { value: newSubtasks } }` which isn't type `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextareaElement>`

Comment: Oh, I see. You might go for `function onChangeFor<K extends keyof ITaskConstructor>(key: K): (e: { target: { value: ITaskConstructor[K] }}) => void`, but I'd suggest to rather a separate `updateTask(key, value)` helper function that you can directly call from task input, instead of having to construct an event-like object only to pass it to `onChange`.